# React-native app keeps crashing on some Android versions

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on an application which already exists on google play store, I made some updates and wanted to release a new update and here's the problem, I built and released a new APK without any error and it works fine on Android 9 but keeps loading then crashes on Android 7 and 8

react-native version: 0.59.10

I didn't install any new packages and tried many solutions but nothing changed

any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: have you consider using a realtime crash reporting tool?

Comment: no, can you recommend one?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to be precise; there is no easy way to debug this issue since you cannot get the exact error on each device. Two solutions are advised, in my opinion:

if its a problem with android 7 & 8 : use an emulator with android 7 or 8 installed and test it there ( keep in mind some devices might have some unknown issue unrelated to your apps like a time where someone phone did not have sufficient memory or ram or storage issues).

the second way which is the best way in my opinion:
1 - Upgrade to the latest version of RN and dependencies 
2-  install Firebase `crashlytics,`  and that will log the errors

Comment: It doesn't happen in the debug mode unfortunately :/ but I mean the app with all the dependencies is already exists on the store and was working fine on every device so how come this happen suddenly?